# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax error

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-insert

I'm trying to create an admin dashboard, and within that same dashboard make an option to add articles. For some reason I'm getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'file'.

This is a part of the code i used for the "news portal" I'm trying to build. This is the server-side code behind the dashboard aspx page.

```
protected void Publish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    con.Open();
    string command = "INSERT INTO Articles(title,author,content,file,tags) VALUES(@title,@author,@content,@file,@tags)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", Title1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", Author.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", Content.Text);
    string strImg = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File1.PostedFile.FileName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file", strImg);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tags", Tag.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Images\\") + strImg);
}
```

I'm getting this error every single time I press the "publish" button.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 2):

It's likely because `file` is a [reserved word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and so you need to surround it with square brackets:

```
string command = "INSERT INTO Articles(title,author,content,[file],tags) VALUES(@title,@author,@content,@file,@tags)";
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! the error disappeared, but a new one came up. "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query."

Comment: So your `file` column is a `varbinary(max)` but you're trying to insert a string against it. You will need to look up how to save a binary file to sql server with a query, rather than just the file name. If you still run into trouble you should ask another question outlining what research you did on it.

Comment: @marom, also avoid [`AddWithValue`](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) and instead specify the proper SQL data types. `VarBinary` with a max length of -1 is appropriate for `varbinary(MAX)` and your client type should be a byte array.